# How to properly install the preview release salesforcedx core plugin

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, cli, preview

On every release I run into some sort of trouble with this testing phase and having the preview CLI core plugin installed. The instructions are short and clear [HERE](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_sf_cli_install_prerelease.htm)

That said, those instructions don't work for me and the preview version does not install and the existing version remains after running the following command:

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
```

[image: Screenshot of commands]

Any idea why the pre-release would fail to install?

UPDATE: This issue has since been resolved, see best answer for details
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an issue in the Salesforce CLI plugin for pre-release. I am going to inform the team about it.

You can uncover the real error by executing below command

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release --log-level=error
```

Here is the original error

> error Couldn't find any versions for "salesforcedx-templates" that matches "49.0.1-0"
>   Error: Couldn't find any versions for "salesforce-alm" that matches "49.0.6"
>       at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/Users/mohith.shrivastava/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.56.1-2773b53bf5/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:721:66)
>       at new MessageError (/Users/mohith.shrivastava/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.56.1-2773b53bf5/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:750:123)
>       at Function. (/Users/mohith.shrivastava/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.56.1-2773b53bf5/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:50545:13)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (/Users/mohith.shrivastava/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.56.1-2773b53bf5/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:310:30)
>       at /Users/mohith.shrivastava/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.56.1-2773b53bf5/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:321:13
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

**UPDATE**

This has been fixed now and you should be able to install the plugin now.

Comment: I will keep updating this answer as I hear more about this.

Comment: CLI team will fix this tomorrow first thing. Thank you

Comment: This is been fixed now.

Comment: Wow - that was quick @Mohith! Thank you for your support with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use pre-release or develop tags of `salesforcedx`.  `salesforcedx` is bundled in the top-level `sfdx-cli.`.

If you want next week's release early, you can say `sfdx update stable-rc` to switch, and `sfdx update stable` to go back to the "main" release.

You can see how pre-release is getting behind: https://www.npmjs.com/package/salesforcedx